# sql server 2016 import utf-8 csv file with fmt

Tags: sql-server, utf-8

I need to import a utf-8 (without BOM) CSV file into SQL server 2016

here a sample of content:
[image]

and it works well using the following query

```
BULK INSERT [test].[dbo].[csv_test]
FROM 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\16052017.csv'
WITH
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
  ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  ,BATCHSIZE      = 50000
  ,DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'
  ,CODEPAGE       = '65001'
  ,FIRSTROW       = 2
  ,TABLOCK
)
```

Since I have several different files I was planning to use the same stored procedure and use the specific format file for each different files, so I should only "translate" the above procedure, and I did in this way:

```
BULK INSERT [test].[dbo].[csv_test]
FROM 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\16052017.csv'
WITH 
( 
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\csv_test.fmt', 
    FIRSTROW = 2 ,
    DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
    CODEPAGE       = '65001'
)
```

where csv_test.fmt is:

```
    13.0
    13
    1       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     1    RegisteredItemN             Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    2       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     2    CountryOfDestination        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    3       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     3    Customer                    Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    4       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     4    Identifier                  Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    5       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     5    Freight                     Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    6       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     6    HAWB                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    7       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     7    MAWB                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    8       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     8    Name                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    9       SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","     9    Address                     Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    10      SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","    10    Postcode                    Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    11      SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","    11    City                        Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    12      SQLNCHAR             0       1000     ","    12    Weight                      Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
    13      SQLNCHAR             0       1000     "\n"   13    Connote                     Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
```

but I get this error:

```
    Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 3 (Customer).

    The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
    Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: truncation would indicate the data is too long for the column, as its unlikely to be so there is an issue with the row delimiter. CRLF is \r\n.

Comment: Yes, CRLF is \r\n but without .fmt it works with \n only: with \r\n it does not work.
Anyway if I change \n to \r\n in .fmt I got the same error, also leaving only 1 row in the csv file (in this way the csv file is 324 character long included the header) I got the same truncation error, although I dimensioned all fields to 500 chars, therefore the full csv file should stay in 1 field and not return truncation error

Comment: ..while if I set as row terminator `\r\0\n\0` or `\n\0` it does not import any rows